# Gradle implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1' not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to add this library to my project and get the following error:

> Could not resolve org.jsoup: jsoup: 1.12.1

I am using Android Studio 3.1.4 and Gradle 4.6

Comment: Could you show us your `build.gradle` file, please?

Comment: // jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'

Answer (score 0):

Check that you added the line inside `dependencies` block of your gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies
    // ...
    // ...

    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to those who answered my question, but after several minutes I found the cause that generates my problem. I just had my android studio in'Offline Work' for the Gradle which implied that I could not download this dependence from 'org.jsoup: jsoup: 1.11.2'

[Only the option should be unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVfrm.png)